# How to get access to ViewHolder reference in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-memory

In my app, I'm using ViewPager in order to inflate fragments with FragmentStatePagerAdapter. each fragment contains RecyclerView. in order to avoid from memory leaks, I have to remove the RecyclerView and its content each time fragment was destroyed.

This is the code:

```
public class MonthFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
        private static final String ARG_MONTH = "MONTH_ID";
        private static final String SELECTION = Contract.Entry.COLUMN_MONTH + " =? ";
        private int monthId;

        private RecyclerView calendar;
        private CalendarAdapter calendarAdapter;

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            TextView monthName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.month_name);
            monthName.setText(String.valueOf(monthId));

            calendar = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
            calendar.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 6));
            calendarAdapter = new CalendarAdapter(monthId);
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(monthId, null, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
            calendar.setAdapter(calendarAdapter);
            calendarAdapter.setCursor(data);

        }

public class CalendarAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CalendarAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final static int CALENDAR_ITEMS = 35;

    private int beginningPosition;
    private int finalPosition;
    private int date;

    private Calendar calendar;
    private Cursor cursor;

    public CalendarAdapter(int monthId) {
        super();
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthId);
        beginningPosition = getBeginningPositionDate();
        finalPosition = getFinalPositionDate();
        date = 1;

    }

    public void setCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public CalendarAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View singleDate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.single_date, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        return new CalendarAdapter.ViewHolder(singleDate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CalendarAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // TODO: set calendar items with dates
        Log.i("tag", "finalPosition" + String.valueOf(finalPosition));
        if (position >= beginningPosition && position < finalPosition) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, date);
            if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
                date++;
            }
            holder.currentDate.setText(String.valueOf(date));
            if (cursor.moveToNext() && date == cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_DAY))) {
                holder.examSubject.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME)));
            }
            date++;

        }
    }

    private int getBeginningPositionDate() {
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        int beginningPosition;
        if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
            beginningPosition = Calendar.SUNDAY - 1;
        } else {
            beginningPosition = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
        }
        return beginningPosition;
    }


    private int getFinalPositionDate() {
        // calculate the last position of the month date on the RecyclerView

        int lastMonthDay = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int saturdayCount = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= lastMonthDay; i++) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, i);
            if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
                saturdayCount++;
            }
        }
        int finalPosition = getBeginningPositionDate() + (lastMonthDay - saturdayCount);
        return finalPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return CALENDAR_ITEMS;
    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public LinearLayout singleDate;
        public TextView currentDate;
        public TextView examSubject;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            singleDate = (LinearLayout) itemView;
            currentDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.current_date);
            examSubject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exam_subject);
        }

    }
```

My question is: How can I get the ViewHolder reference of each item in the RecyclerView? (after that I will set each item contents to null. it should solve my problem)

Comment: I don't think you need to explicitly clean up the recyclerview. It is handled by the android framework. Are you facing any memory leaks?

Comment: nope. I didn't know that it handled by the Android framework.
but still, how to clean the adapter? ( I want to clean the data from the memory, not just from the UI)

Comment: if you just clear your list and call notifyDatasetChanged, it will clear everything from the recyclerview. Eventually your viewholders will be released from the memory